# I need to serialize an xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

The following code is supposed to read from an XML file and display results in the console:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program introToVCS = new Program();
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new
           System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(introToVCS.GetType());

        // Read the XML file.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("Customer.xml");

        // Deserialize the content of the file into a Program object.
        introToVCS = (Program)reader.Deserialize(file);
        Console.WriteLine(introToVCS);
        Console.ReadLine();                                    
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what is wrong.

Comment: Could you post the customer.xml file please.

Comment: Include pathname for the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Use you filename including path

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
        }
     }
 
}
```